# Connection between optimal exponential smoothing and autocorrelation

Tags: time-series, random-walk

Say we have a Bernoulli random walk with time evolving parameter $\theta_t$ which varies pretty smoothly in small increments over time. We have $n+1$ observations of $x_i$. Intuitively, if we wanted to estimate $\theta_{n+1}$ based on $\hat{\theta}_{1:n}$ and $x_{0:n}$, we can use something along the lines of $\hat{\theta}_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \hat{\theta}_i$ where $\alpha_i$ is some exponentially decreasing weight. We can find the optimal weights by solving some nonlinear optimization problem.

What I'm wondering is, if we look at the autocorrelation of $\hat{\theta}$, we should see some kind of decreasing function of the lag $\tau$ if our assumption of vanishing predictivity holds. So what would be the problem of using a scaled version of the autocorrelation as our weights? What I mean is, the impulse response of our exponential smoothing filter should share a lot of the same properties as the autocorrelation function.

My guess is that if the autocorrelation is 0.99 for $\tau$ and 0.495 for $\tau'$, you'd want to place *a lot* more than twice the weight on the observation at $\tau$?